# Filtering X most recent entries in each category of queryset

Tags: django, django-orm

Question is regarding  filtering X most recent entries in each category of queryset.

Goal is like this:

I have a incoming queryset based on the following model.

```
class UserStatusChoices(models.TextChoices):
    CREATOR = 'CREATOR'
    SLAVE = 'SLAVE'
    MASTER = 'MASTER'
    FRIEND = 'FRIEND'
    ADMIN = 'ADMIN'
    LEGACY = 'LEGACY'


class OperationTypeChoices(models.TextChoices):
    CREATE = 'CREATE'
    UPDATE = 'UPDATE'
    DELETE = 'DELETE'


class EntriesChangeLog(models.Model):
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(
        ContentType,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(
    )
    content_object = GenericForeignKey(
        'content_type',
        'object_id',
    )
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        get_user_model(),
        verbose_name='user',
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        related_name='access_logs',
    )
    access_time = models.DateTimeField(
        verbose_name='access_time',
        auto_now_add=True,
    )
    as_who = models.CharField(
        verbose_name='Status of the accessed user.',
        choices=UserStatusChoices.choices,
        max_length=7,
    )
    operation_type = models.CharField(
        verbose_name='Type of the access operation.',
        choices=OperationTypeChoices.choices,
        max_length=6,
    )
```

And I need to filter this incoming queryset in a such way to keep only 4 most recent objects (defined by `access_time` field) in each category. Categories are defined by ‘`content_type_id`’ field and there are 3 possible options.
Lets call it ‘`option1`’, ‘`option2`’ and ‘`option3`’

This incoming queryset might contain different amount of objects of 1,2 or all 3 categories. This is can’t be predicted beforehand.
`DISTINCT` is not possible to use as after filtering operation this queryset might be ordered.

I managed to get 1 most recent object in a following way:

```
# get one most recent operation in each category

last_operation_time = Subquery(
   EntriesChangeLog.objects.filter(user=OuterRef('user')).values('content_type_id').
    annotate(last_access_time=Max(‘access_time’)).values_list('last_access_time', flat=True)
)

queryset.filter(access_time__in=last_operation_time)
```

But I have a hard time to figure out how to get last 4 most recent objects instead of last one.
This is needed for Django-Filter and need to be done in one query.

DB-Postgres 12

Do you have any ideas how to do such filtration?

Thanks...
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
pk_to_rank = queryset.annotate(rank=Window(
            expression=DenseRank(),
            partition_by=('content_type_id',),
            order_by=F('access_time').desc(),
        )).values_list('pk', 'rank', named=True)

        pks_list = sorted(log.pk for log in pk_to_rank if log.rank <= value)

        return queryset.filter(pk__in=pks_list)
```

Managed to do it only this way by spliting queryset in 2 parts. Option with 3 unions is also possible but what if we have 800 options instead 3 - make 800 unions()??? ges not...